Horror/Thriller Movie With A Killer Collecting Bodies
I remember seeing this movie on TV as a kid (it was early 2000s) but I can't quite remember what the name was. But I do remember a couple of scenes:

One of the main characters who was a guy, falls into a pit and sees body bags full of bones
At the end of the movie, we see the killer standing behind the standing body of the guy main character, with the guy's eyes removed so you can kinda see the killers eyes behind him. The main character was holding his arms up to his sides I think during this scene.
There was a scene where the killer jumps on the moving car of the people trying to escape.


Hi. Do you remember the approximate year and the country\language?

This seems familiar somehow, but I can't pin it down.  Any other details you might be able to remember could help.  Physical appearance of the actors, the year you saw it.  What colour was the car?  Anything. :)

It was early 2000s. -I asked this on a couple of other websites as well, and it turned out to be "Jeepers Creepers". Thanks regardless

It was Jeepers Creepers, 2001. Here is an IMDb extract.

On their way back home during the spring break, Darry and Patricia Jenner witness a mysterious person dumping something down a tunnel. Deciding to discover what was dumped down there, Darry discovers a huge disturbing hideout full of modified bodies. Darry and Patricia set off to get help, unaware that the individual is now aware of who has been down the tunnel. Darry and Patricia soon realizes that their pursuer is not just a mysterious person, but something even more horrifying, who has more in store than they could possibly imagine. 

The demon at the end is whistling the Jeepers Creepers tune (Where'd you get those eyes?) as he stands behind the victim that "donated" his eyes.
Here is a trailer:



